# Eclipse says "source not found" when I debug my app after changing default launching activity

Tags: android, eclipse

Whenever I change the default activity in my AndroidManifest.xml file, a debug error comes up and says:

```
'Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException)) 
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2249    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2299 
ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 154    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1284  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5306    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 511  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 1102 
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 869 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  

Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) '
```

And then in the shared area, it shows "source not found" with a button that says "Edit Source Lookup Path". My Android Manifest looks like this

```
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tobidae.problem"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.tobidae.problem.MAINMENU" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>   
</manifest>'
```

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

If you continue your program (press 'Continue' on your IDE), an exception will be thrown and you will be able to read it in LogCat. The 'Source not found' error means that the exception was generated with the Android framework code, and not in your classes; this probably means that it can't find the specified activity (or can't instantiate the class) and throws an exception.